# qt showing non-latin special characters in QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, qt, unicode, pyside

I am attempting to show some chess pieces in a QTableWidget through a QTableWidgetItem but when i do i do not get the desired output. Here is the relevant code.

```
 def __str__(self):
    if self.colour == "White":
        return '♖'
    else:
        return '♜'

if self.board.board[y][x]:
    item.setText(str(self.board.board[y][x]))
self.chess_board.setItem(y, x, item)
```

The first function is a function of the class. The if statement is where the data is inserted into the table (x,y come from a for loop and item is an instance of QTableWidgetItem). 
The output i expect is ♜. However the output i get is □. 
In fact as I copied what was in the table onto the browser it showed as the piece however on the table is it shown as the square above.

Thank you for the comment but i still have problems. At school on a windows 7 computer it works fine. On a windows 10 computer at home i end up with this using QtableWidget and QTableWidgetItem with PySide.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bnub.jpg

I noticed that when i output to the command line, whilst the characters still print, I get a UnicodeEncodeError regardless what computer I use

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: It's a bit late where I am but I gave it a quick read and I'll give it a closer look tomorrow morning; do i need to use these comments if I already save my files with a unicode utf-8 encoding?

Comment: in second line of source add following line: `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` and make sure that your text editor encodes source code in UTF-8. This should resolve problems with python string literals. I'm not sure how this will work with qt, but IMO conversion to Qt string should go without problems. [It should work since python 2.3](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-encodings.html).

Comment: Read my new edit pls. Unfortunately this suggestion has helped, the problem may be different...

Comment: From the picture I can see that it in fact this worked. Problem is the font which doesn't cover this Unicode characters, that is why it prints rectangle. Try different font and make sure this font supports chess pieces.

Comment: I thought so to, but as I mentioned earlier, the font shows correctly on a windows 7 pc at home but shows rectangles (as in the picture) in windows 10. I also used the Arial Unicode MS font and Tahoma font which have chess pieces. I have a nudge that this is due to a difference in windows 7/10 but I'm not sure as to eactly what: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode

Comment: add some text edit with this font and paste this character to see outcome and make sure that font supports this character.